# Browse Button is missing in Enterprise Keywords field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016

I have added **Enterprise Keywords** field to one of my content types as well as another metadata field. When I try to edit my page which uses this content type, I cannot see the browse link in Enterprise Keywords field, but I can see it in other custom managed metadata field. Please see below screenshot.

Is there any way to show same button for this Enterprise Keywords(Tags) field too?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks